# What is the difference between FormUrlEncodedContent and query string?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm doing some web scraping using the following methods

This is successful for most websites.

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("v1", "value1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("v2", "value2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("v3", "value3"),
});
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://url.com", content);
html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Sometimes certain website needs this way to get response.

```
var url = "http://url.com?v1=value1&v2=value2&v3=value3";
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, null);
html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And sometimes needs this to get response.

```
var query = "v1=value1&v2=value2&v3=value3";
var content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query));
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://url.com", content);
html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I really have no idea what is the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `FormUrlEncodedContent` your parameters will be sent in request body and formatted as query string.

```
POST http://url.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: url.com
Content-Length: 29
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

v1=value1&v2=value2&v3=value3
```

In the second case parameters will be sent as query part of URL.

```
POST http://url.com/?v1=value1&v2=value2&v3=value3 HTTP/1.1
Host: url.com
Content-Length: 0
```

In the third case you sent a content of `query` in the request body.

In your sample it has the same effect as in the first case, but you made formatting by hand.

Comment: Does it mean the server only accept request body or url parameter only?

Comment: Yes @derodevil, it depends on how server processes the request. In one case it expects to get parameters from the request body and in other case from query part of URL.

Answer (score 2):

The URL (query string) has a (browser dependant) size limit. The body of a POST request doesn't have this limit. So you would use the body to send a file.

On the other hand, a URL can be used in a link.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're sending a `POST` request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload in the request body
2. You're *supposedly* sending a `POST` request, with no payload, but it still works because the endpoint *probably* accepts querystring as the payload as with `GET` requests (instead of request body)
3. You're sending a `POST` to a resource that expects byte array payload

Hth